# Replacing Drywall

Tags: drywall, walls, patching-drywall

I have roughly a 12 foot long (horizontal wise) section of drywall that needs to be replaced.  Watching videos and reading tutorials online, it seems straightforward and easy enough to do.  I have 2 questions regarding the process

1) One section of the drywall has a lightswitch, do I just remove the faceplate, and once the drywall is removed the receptacle will "pop-out"?

2) A diff portion of the drywayll contains my AC unit thermostat - how do I get that "out" w/o damaging the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Turn off the power to the switch, remove the face plate and then the switch. You don't need to un-wire the switch. You will need to cut the new drywall to go around the wall box. Cut it so its a relatively tight fit so that when the face plate is put back on, there are no gaps around the edges.

2) Same thing applies here as it did to the light switch. Pull your thermostat off (different ways from different manufacturers) take a picture of the wiring so you can put it back together right. Unhook the wires and remove the thermostat base plate. make sure your new drywall has the hole knocked in it at the same spot, or a new location if you like, for the wires to go back through to re-install the thermostat.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the information!  I was concerned with the lightswitch I would have to unwire then rewire, but this is MUCH easier tahn I was expecting!  Is a drywall knife my best bet for making a clean cut to replace these two items?

Comment: If you want to to be easy and not mess with the switch in the way, you can take a picture of it too and un-wire and remove it. But I usually just leave it dangle unless I need to power it back on while working.

Comment: As for cutting, I suggest a drywall saw. they are small and have a pointed end. They are pretty rigid so you can stab them into the drywall, make your cut and be done. The saws are usually under $10 and even Wal-Mart has them, sometimes around $5. A knife would work too, but then you have to score and x hatch all the way through to get it to come out. More work than necessary

Answer (score 0):

Just to support @JeffCates comments the following is what a drywall stab saw looks like:

[image]